# Can you exclude macOS devices from AirDrop in an UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, airdrop

I am trying to make our iOS app only recognize iOS devices when sharing a file through AirDrop in an `UIActivityViewController`. Here is the code I am using to initialize the view controller.

```
var fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myBusinessCard", withExtension: nil)!
let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Sharing File", fileUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
controller.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToTwitter, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo, UIActivityType.mail, UIActivityType.message] // UIActivityType.airDrop
self.present(controller,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have already made a new UTI for our file type so that it will automatically be opened by the correct app.

Comment: Answer for your title question - "No, you can't".

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to restrict the people/devices that show up.